# Add audio track to MKV

Tags: aac, dts, mkv

I have several MKV files in several folders. I wanted to be able to add a Video track & Audio track that is supported by my TV.

1. It's ALL MKV files (but in multiple different folders)
2. Obviously I do not want to add another track if the required track already exists

So let's say I got a MKV with a DTS Audio track. After the convertion the MKV would both have the original DTS Audio track and a AAC Audio track.

I am thinking of a powershell script where I run a command to extract information about existing tracks and the based on that add required tracks.

If anyone can point me to the right tool I would be very happy.

UPDATE:
I found that "mediainfo" seems like a great tool for the "get information about the mkv part". Which means that I only need a tool for the update mkv file part

Comment: What have you tried so far?  and what programming language do you intend to  use? Extra information is needed for someone to be able to help you.

Comment: I have been looking at handbrake but I am not sure I can use this out of the box.
The programming language would just be PowerShell or something like that.
So any tool with some sort of command line interface would be great.